# Page not found without record about page

Tags: 7

Is there a way to find the source of an error that I have on my production site during the last few days? In reports/dblog I see an error "Page not found" but there is no any information about what page, source, time of this error.

**EDIT** I looked in phpmyadmin and saw the source of the problem. The error appears when user reposts node in livejournal. I don't know is it a big problem for website or not (I mean problems with perfomance or search engines). Does anyone know the answer on this last question?

Comment: Did you replace new site with old one recently?

Comment: not, it's absolutely the new one

Comment: Have you cross checked with google analytics if its configure you can check with list of page not found pages with detail.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something you're experiencing personally or are you just looking at the logs?

If you're just looking at the logs, it's usually a spammer/bot/crawler that's triggering the response. There are some security modules you can install that gives you a little more insight into those kinds of things (such as the IP address that triggered it), but I can only think of the D6 ones right now.

Comment: usually I see activity of spam bots (these records exist in dblog), that's why it a bit strange I do not have records about and error despite the just "page not found"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in open graph meta property="og:url" with token [site:url]. In practice it was looking like example.com/ and as there is no page on my site with url example.com/ (there is example.com without slash) drupal recorded it as an error 404 when people came from other sites where the link was posted